# Java - handing file deletion

Tags: java, ffmpeg

So I am using the `youtube-dl` command line program within Java with simple command line execute function and coupling it with `ffmpeg` to convert to mp3. Now the thing I am having trouble with it the fact that after I get the `.mp4` file from `youtube-dl`, when I convert it into a `.mp3`, it will create a completely separate file.

So the way it is now:

```
1. Get `.mp4`
2. Get `.mp3`
3. delete `.mp4'
```

The issue I am facing now is that if the user was to stop the program while it was between `step 1` and `step 2`, then they would be left with the `.mp4` file which is not wanted. So is there a way to delete certain files once the user exits the process, whether it being from safely ending the program (this one should be easy), ending the process, or closing the computer?

Comment: Including the relevant code would help us help you. If the user kills the java process then there is no way the process can do anything after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a temporary directory, download and transcode the video file into that directory, move out the mp3 file as an additional step and leave it up to the VM to delete the entire directory on exit?

1. create temporary directory
2. mark it for [deletion on exit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit--)
3. do your thing
4. move mp3 file to non-temporary location

However, this only works if the VM terminates normally. You could add another step that checks whether your temporary directory exists and delete it during ramp-up of your application to clean up after yourself on those cases where the VM exited abnormally.

Comment: I see what you are saying so if there was a crash or if the user ends the process prematurely, the next time when I start the program have a quick check to see if the temp directory has anything inside or if so, delete it. Thanks this works

Comment: @QQMusic, it depends on your understanding of "prematurely". As long as the VM is "killed" by the user with a [signal](http://journal.thobe.org/2013/02/jvms-and-kill-signals.html) that allows the VM to run its registered shutdown hooks, then your temp directory will be deleted. If the VM is "force killed" or crashes then the deletion on exit won't happen.